# 'Insert if not exists'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any way I can insert into, if values not exists in any row?
Let's say I have a table:

```
id(auto_increment)|id_user|id_translation
------------------------------------------
39                |5      | 20
-
```

Tried

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `usertranslation`(`id_translation`, `id_user`) VALUES ('20','5')
WHERE not EXISTS (
    SELECT * from `usertranslation`
    WHERE `id_translation` = '20' AND
    `id_user` = '5' )
```

And similar with replace, but nothing works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For prevent duplicates in table the  [`UNIQUE` constraints](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-unique/) must be used.
So first you need to change your table like:

```
ALTER TABLE `usertranslation`
ADD CONSTRAINT `unique_user_transaction` UNIQUE KEY(`id_translation`, `id_user`);
```

After table changed you can use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `usertranslation`(`id_translation`, `id_user`) VALUES ('20','5');
```

Pay attention `INSERT IGNORE` prevent error on attempt to insert duplicates, but increase auto increment field as well.

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `usertranslation`(`id_translation`, `id_user`) VALUES ('20','5')
```

which will not insert the new row (without an error) if there are existing constraints which are conflicting with the new row,
or `INSERT` with `SELECT` and **not** `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO `usertranslation`(`id_translation`, `id_user`) 
SELECT '20', '5'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (    
  SELECT 1 from `usertranslation`
  WHERE `id_translation` = '20' AND `id_user` = '5' 
)
```